# How to fix "Bus error 10" after update to Xcode 10.2

Tags: cocoapods, ipa, bus-error, xcode10.2

I updated Xcode to new stable 10.2v. I tried to build my project and it was successful. When I'm trying to archive the project (workspace), I'm getting errors like on screenshot below:

[image]

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Update cocoa pods to latest version -> COCOAPODS: 1.7.0.beta.3
2. Clean DeliveredData folder
3. Reinstall Xcode
4. Remove repository, clone it again and install pods
5. Totally remove all pods from project and add them back

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Temporary Workaround

For me it was only the `Cache` framework. Until they have fixed it, you can manually set `SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL` to `-Onone` for the configuration you want to use for archiving.

[image]

## CocoaPods

You could even use your Podfile if you don't want Cococapods to overwrite the settings every time you run `pod install`

```rb
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            if target.name == 'Cache'
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '-Onone'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

> Note that this is specifically checking for the `Cache` framework. If you have problems with other frameworks you might want to change or extend this condition.

Answer (score 3):

While Lukas' answer of disabling optimization on the Cache pod works, I followed Alex's link to the issue in their GitHub repo and found there is an open pull request with a pretty simple code change that fixes it.  I unlocked the file and made the change locally.

Here's the PR: https://github.com/hyperoslo/Cache/pull/236

Apply this diff: https://github.com/hyperoslo/Cache/pull/236/commits/560f00a9a9549db161ca70d96eed74fc580b03e3#diff-9e53dc1370d4f7c9cdaaa103d26ff096

Which, to repeat here, is in the file MD5.swift change the `safe_add` function to be:

```swift
func safe_add(_ x: Int32, _ y: Int32) -> Int32 {
  return x &+ y
}
```

*(Disclaimer: I do not claim to know the correctness of the change, but it seems the delay merging the PR is due to figuring out who is currently maintaining the repo.)*

Comment: Chadwick you're a godsend, thanks for linking that here

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here: https://github.com/hyperoslo/Cache/issues/238

We are waiting for the owners of this repo to make any sign of life...